# Play music automatically when starting app

Tags: android, kotlin

I was wondering how to make the music play automatically when starting the app and how to make it stop playing in the background when pressing the home button. Right now, it starts and stops by pressing the toggle button. I was also wondering if its possible to automatically switch to other music when going to another activity?

MainActivity.kt

```
 private lateinit var player: MediaPlayer

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val secondActivity = findViewById<Button>(R.id.secondActivity)
        secondActivity.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        val toggle: ToggleButton = findViewById(R.id.toggleButton)
        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            val svc = Intent(this, MusicService::class.java)
            if (isChecked) {
                startService(svc)
            } else {
                stopService(svc)
            }
        }
    }
```

MusicService.kt

```
class MusicService : Service() {

    private lateinit var player: MediaPlayer

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        TODO("Return the communication channel to the service.")
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music)
        player.setLooping(true)
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        player.start()
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        player.stop()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your specific requirements, you should or shouldn't use a `MediaService` as part of your solution.

To be more clear, a `Service` should only be used if you want the audio to keep going whenever you're outside the app. This solution will usually be accompanied by a media Notification which you should populate with controls, image assets, etc. (Think of Spotify or SoundCloud) If this is the solution you're looking for, take a look at this [doc page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/media-apps-overview) from Google and follow it through. Beware that this is a longer and tougher process to maintain.

On the other hand, if all you want to do is play music/sounds while your user is inside your app, then a simple

```kt
private lateinit var localMedia: MediaPlayer

override fun onCreate() {
    ...
    localMedia = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.your_audio_file)
}

override fun onResume() {
    ...
    localMedia.start()
}

override fun onPause() {
    ...
    localMedia.release()
}
```

Furthermore, if you want different audio files to be played on different Activities/Fragments, you might want to abstract the code I provided above into it's own Manager class or so and access it the same but changing the specific .mp3 file (or whatever format) as you see fit.

### EDIT:

For a Manager class, you'll have to create your own functions and handle the `MediaPlayer` inside of it

```
private class MediaPlayerManager(private val context: Context) {

private lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer

fun setupPlayer() {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.your_audio_file)
}

fun play() {
    mediaPlayer.start()
}

fun stop() {
    mediaPlayer.stop()
}
}
```

And call these functions from their respective lifecycle method inside your Activity/Fragment, *depending on your specific needs*

```
class YourActivity {

val mediaPlayerManager = MediaPlayerManager(context)

override onCreate() {
    ...
    mediaPlayerManager.setupPlayer()
}

override fun onResume() {
    ...
    mediaPlayerManager.play()
}

override fun onPause() {
    ...
    mediaPlayerManager.stop()
}
}
```

I should add that I'm not necessarily providing a fully-fledged answer here, but a starting point for you to massage to your own needs. The Manager class is nothing but an abstraction of the concept I'm trying to communicate. Lastly, if you want to use a different audio resource file in another Activity/Fragment, you would have to create a method to re-assign the `MediaPlayer` object inside it with the appropriate file.
E.g.

```
fun setupPlayer(audioRes: Int) {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, audioRes)
}
```

Comment: If you release in onPause, you'll need to create a new instance onResume before starting it again.

Comment: I get error 'onCreate' overrides nothing, 'onResume' overrides nothing and 'onPause' overrides nothing when adding the code into a Manager class

Comment: @user14522467 well yes ofc, that is to be expected; only `Activity` and `Fragment` classes have those functions to override. If you're going to abstract this solution into a Manager class, you'll have to create your own functions on it, and call them in their respective lifecycle methods inside your Acitivty/Fragment. Let me update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: val mediaPlayerManager = MediaPlayerManager(context) gives error Unresolved reference: context. What does this mean?

Comment: I means that you need to pass an actual context reference. Are you trying to create this object from an Activity or a Fragment? @user14522467

Comment: From an Activity

Comment: @user14522467 You'll have to use 'applicationContext' instead. In theory, any reference to a `Context` should work.

Comment: @IvanGarza When running the app, it crashes and says that it unfortunately has stopped. Should the code you provided play music?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before
create a Class and named it (for example I named it `C`) and extend that from `Application` like following (don't forget put `android:name=".C"`  in `<application>` tag in manifest.xml):

```
class C:Application() {
  fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    context = getApplicationContext()
    app = this
  }
  companion object {
    private val context:Context
    var currentActivity:Activity
    var currentActivities:ArrayList<Activity> = ArrayList()
    var handler:Handler
    var app:C
    fun get():C {
      return app
    }

    fun getContext():Context {
      if (currentActivity != null)
      {
        return currentActivity
      }
      return context
    }
  }
}
```

I created a class for parent of `AppCompatActivity` and (named `UAppCompactActivity`)extend it form `AppCompatActivity`  then extend all activities from `UAppCompactActivity`:

```
abstract class UAppCompatActivity:AppCompatActivity() {
  fun onCreate(@Nullable savedInstanceState:Bundle, @Nullable persistentState:PersistableBundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
  }
  protected fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    C.setCurrentActivity(this)
    C.currentActivities.add(this)
    /* you can play your music here or do any action you desired */
  }

  protected fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    C.currentActivities.remove(this)
    /* 
        you can stop your music here or do any action you desired

        if (UBase.currentActivities.size() === 0)
           G.backgroundMusics.get(G.app.musicNumberBackAndNowPlay).pause()
        else
           play music or switch to new music
    */
    
  }

}
```